# How to fix "await is only valid in async function" even when await is in an async function in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I have some sample code I'm trying to run, and I want some asynchronous function that is executing to be called synchronously. **I know you need to add async to the function in order to have an await.** I've already done that. Still though I get the following error:

```
  let result = await promise;
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

For context here is my code:

```js
async function main() {
  var client = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Protocol);
  fs.stat(filePath, function (err, fileStats) {
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {

    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      client.uploadToBlob('testblob.txt', fileStream, fileStats.size, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('error uploading file: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Upload successful - ' + result);
        }
        res(i);
      });
    })
    let result = await promise;
    console.log(result);
  }

  fileStream.destroy();
  });
}

main();
```

**Why am I getting said error when my function is already async?**

Comment: ```fs.stat(filePath, function (err, fileStats) {``` *this* function also needs to be async.

Comment: `fs.stat(filePath, function (err, fileStats) {` – everything is inside this callback function, which is not an async function… even if you unindent the code so it looks like it’s not in that function. Use `let fileStats = await fs.promises.stat(filePath)`.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi: Putting async on a callback function is generally incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use async-await inside a function that is not marked with async (your callback).

Just make your callback an async-await function.

```js
async function main() {
  var client = Client.fromConnectionString(deviceConnectionString, Protocol);
  fs.stat(filePath, async function (err, fileStats) {
  var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

  for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {

    let promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      client.uploadToBlob('testblob.txt', fileStream, fileStats.size, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('error uploading file: ' + err.constructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Upload successful - ' + result);
        }
        res(i);
      });
    })
    let result = await promise;
    console.log(result);
  }

  fileStream.destroy();
  });
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

`let result = await promise;` 
the above statement reside within new Promise callback handler which is again a anonymous function.

So, one has to put async against with this function as well as it associated with new scope which is nothing a new promise object.

```
let promise = new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
```